# Woocommerce: Error when customers try to add more than remaining stock

Tags: woocommerce

Hi I used the latest WP and WC. The add to cart button keeps spinning when customers add more than the remaining stock. They could purchase 2 pcs and another 2 pcs while there are only 2 in stock.

The error on console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (HTTP/2.0 500) ----/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

WC show the error msg on front: 
**You cannot add that amount to the cart — we have 2 in stock and you already have 2 in your cart.** only when I refresh the page.

I dont want to allow backorde and I search around already. So what is the solution I can try? Please Kindly help. Thanks, the community!

Comment: So there is certainly a generated javascript error maid by some customizations you have maid or your theme or some third party plugin… You should inspect the page with your browser developer tools and you will see on the console that there is some javascript errors… Anyway **this question is just of topic on stackOverFlow** as we don't handle any software support.

Comment: Hi yes, I found it on console. It is caused by a plugin. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome … This is always mostly the case as Woocommerce globally works well…